# Read limited number of rows from excel file in R with read_excel

Tags: r, readxl

I am reading in excel files in R using the readxl package like this:

```
library(readxl)
file_names <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")

list_collection <- list() 
for(i in 1:length(file_names)){
  frame <- read_excel(file_names[i], )
  frame_sub <- frame[1:100,]
  list_collection[i] <- list(frame_sub)  
}
```

Since there are a lot of excel files, and I only want the first 100 rows. Obviously this is not efficient. Is there a way to read in only 100 rows from excel initially, instead of reading in this whole file and THEN subsetting?

Comment: this has been discussed at some length on the [readxl issues list ...](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/8) don't know when it will see the light of day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `xlsx::read.xlsx()` instead. It has arguments for specifying the start and end rows.  Also note that I have made some improvements to your `for()` loop (memory allocation being the most important).

```
library(xlsx)
## get file names
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
## allocate memory for our list
out <- vector("list", length(file_names)) 
## read the files and assign them to the list
for(i in seq_along(file_names)) {
    out[[i]] <- read.xlsx(file_names[i], startRow = 1, endRow = 100)  
}
```

Or you could do a named list by changing the `for()` loop to

```
for(file in file_names) {
    out[[file]] <- read.xlsx(file, startRow = 1, endRow = 100)  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Came across this while searching for the same thing - this has been added to the latest `readxl` update. To get the first 100 rows in your sheet you could do

```
library(readxl)
file_names <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")

list_collection <- list() 
for(i in 1:length(file_names)){
  frame <- read_excel(file_names[i], n_max = 100)
  list_collection[i] <- list(frame)  
}
```

Or you could specify particular rows using something like

```
frame <- read_excel(file_names[i], range = cell_rows(1:100))
```